# load_files only works from the swi prolog shell?

Tags: swi-prolog

From the swi prolog shell I can load prolog files using load_files(filename).

But if I call load_files from a prolog file does not work.

I'm new at prolog.

I tried to end the file with .pl or put the name of the file between "" or ''.

The following do not work:

Contents of file1.pl: 
dog(a).
dog(b).

Contents of file2.pl:
dog(c).
load_files(file1).

If now from the prolog shell I do load_files(file2) it doesn't load the dogs a and b.

If I do this, the following error is shown:
?- load_files(file2).
true.

?- dog(M).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: dog/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `include()` predicate to load the contents of a file. So in `file2.pl`, you would have:

```
dog(c).
:- include("file1.pl").
```

The contents of `file2.pl` will be loaded right after `dog(c).`

Comment: I changed load_files(file1) for :-load_files(file1) and it works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome! I did not know `load_files()` could be used as a directive. So you did not use the `include()` predicate?

Comment: I need that when I load a prolog file, all old clauses have to be replaced by the new ones from the new prolog file. I do not know if "include" do the same.